# Why don't the UITableViewCell's self size cell work in iOS8.3?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

UITableViewCell's self size cell worked well in iOS8.2, But when I updated Xcode6.3 it doesn't work.

Who can tell me the reason?

```
override fun viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please. Post. Relevant. Code.

Comment: @Fogmeister Your blog example is in objective-C :), this is a swift question. Not that it matters without code reference from the OP

Comment: @Chackle that's irrelevant anyway. The SDK is the same for Objective-C and Swift. Same methods, same functions, same properties. The code is a bit different but that's all.

Comment: @Fogmeister I know how to use self-sizing cell, I mean is it work well in iOS8.2 but not work in iOS8.3!

Comment: @Fogmeister This is a question marked as Swift. It's perfectly relevant.

Comment: @YuXuanFu can you show the auto layout constraints on the label please. Just select the label before taking the screen shot.

Comment: @Chackle I know how to use self-sizing cell, I mean is it work well in iOS8.2 but not work in iOS8.3!

Comment: @Fogmeister I have posted the screen shot about layout constraints.

Comment: @Fogmeister Do you run your demo in iOS8.3? Does the Self-Sizing cell work well?

Comment: @Chackle, irrelevant whether it is a _Swift_ or _ObjC_ question, as long as every professional iOS developer must be familiar with both languages by now; on the other hand the API is the same...

Comment: @Fogmeister I make `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`, But still not work.

Comment: Try setting the estimated rowheight just before "self.tableview.rowheight".  So something like this... self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50

Comment: @YuXuanFu ok, now I'm eating my words. Just tested on the iOS8.3 release and my demo is broken...

Comment: @KevinHorgan I tried, It doesn't work too.

Comment: @Fogmeister Yes, I downloaded your demo, It broken.

Comment: @YuXuanFu I added an answer now, it fixes my demo.

Comment: Can you please give a `Preferred Width` (in this case, 400) by accepting the check box `Explicit`?

Comment: @x4h1d No. the `Explicit` is uncheck!

Comment: @YuXuan Fu, check it and give a `preferred width`.

Comment: @x4h1d I tried, But still not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just tested my demo code on release iOS 8.3 and it is broken.

It ONLY work with the following code...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;

    // set cell values...
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

If I try to put `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` then it doesn't work.

Make sure to set the estimatedRowHeight and then to use the heightForRow method to set the auto dimension.

**EDIT**

Possibly because your tableview isn't static try removing the line... `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100;` and using...

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 100;
}
```

Just a guess...

I think in Swift this is...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 100
}
```

Comment: Jesus, Why my demo still not work...

Comment: @YuXuanFu without seeing it in more detail... no idea.

Comment: @YuXuanFu did you edit my demo project and get it working?

Comment: Yes, I edited your demo and it working!

Comment: @YuXuanFu check my latest edited. Worth a try.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you write a simple demo use Swift?

Comment: My tableview is prototype cell.

Comment: I had this problem and my current code was `tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. I had to add `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100` and then it worked.